# Can Jetty be installed on ubuntu server?

Tags: java, php, database, jetty

I plan on using solr on my VPS.

My server is Ubuntu.

Does anybody know if Jetty can run without problems on Ubuntu, just as in the example Solr distribution?

With Tomcat it is possible, but my Q is, is it possible with Jetty?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have run several internal applications for a while on Jetty on Ubuntu and Debian. This works absolutely fine.

We bundle everything in a debian package and distribute it complete, appserver wars and jars as one package.

This is a lot easier than deploying on the standard tomcat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Works fine.